# Empty output file in systemd unit file

Tags: linux, centos, systemd, kms

**Edited!!!!**

I used this unit file and here is the output but it won't create any log files.

```
[Unit]
Description=PY-KMS
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/py-kms-master/server.py 192.168.1.100 1688 -v
StandardOutput=/usr/local/py-kms-master/kms.log
StandardError=/usr/local/py-kms-master/kms-error.log


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Status:**

```
[root@static ~]# systemctl status pykms -l
pykms.service - PY-KMS
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pykms.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2015-11-24 20:26:44 IRST; 3s ago
 Main PID: 2705 (server.py)
   CGroup: /system.slice/pykms.service
           └─2705 /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/py-kms-master/server.py 192.168.1.100 1688 -v

Nov 24 20:26:44 static.clients.your-server.de systemd[1]: Starting PY-KMS...
Nov 24 20:26:44 static.clients.your-server.de systemd[1]: Started PY-KMS.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it's not necessary (and looks very bad) to use a shell script to start up a process in a systemd unit. Nor is it necessary to call a Python interpreter explicitly, if your Python script has the correct line at the top of it.

Start by cleaning up the unit file:

```
[Service]
#...
ExecStart=/usr/local/py-kms-master/server.py 192.168.1.100 1688 -v
StandardOutput=/usr/local/py-kms-master/kms.log
StandardError= (whatever you want)
```

Second, look in the correct file. Your service is logging to `kms.log` but you have been looking at `kms-server.txt`. Either look at the other file, or change the destination.

Comment: thank you I used your code but it won't start and gives the error below:

Comment: Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pykms.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2015-11-24 13:00:56 IRST; 1min 27s ago
  pykms.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Nov 24 13:00:56 static.27.79.47.78.clients.your-server.de systemd[1]: Unit pykms.service entered failed state.

Comment: How can I use python interpreter inside this code?

Comment: my python script (server.py) has these lines at the top of it:import argparse
import binascii
import hashlib
import random
import socket
import SocketServer
import struct
import uuid
import rpcBind, rpcRequest

from dcerpc import MSRPCHeader
from rpcBase import rpcBase

Comment: It should start with something like `#!/usr/bin/python2.7` See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/using/unix.html#miscellaneous).

Comment: I added the above line at the top of my server.py file and restarted the server but it gives the error :  (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Comment: any idea? this is so important for me.

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: @GregL the script works now but it won't create log files. there is no errors too. I used simple service type and also tried oneshot and forking but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try (overwrite):

```
StandardOutput=file:/usr/local/py-kms-master/kms.log
StandardError=file:/usr/local/py-kms-master/kms-error.log
```

or (append)

```
StandardOutput=append:/usr/local/py-kms-master/kms.log
StandardError=append:/usr/local/py-kms-master/kms-error.log
```

if you have systemd > 240 and, since it's a python script, set the -u flag, or set:

```
Environment="PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1"
```

in the unit file so that python doesn't buffer its output for a long time before flushing it to systemd to log.